# Cannot access nested property in nestjs - Property 'isDeleted' does not exist on type '() => Company'

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongoose, nestjs

**company.entity.ts**

```
@Schema({
  timestamps: true,
  versionKey: false,
})
export class Company {
  @Prop({ type: String, trim: true, required: true })
  name: string;

  @Prop({ type: String, trim: true, required: true })
  address: string;

  @Prop({ type: Boolean, required: true, default: false })
  isDeleted: boolean;

  @Prop({
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    required: true,
    ref: 'User',
  })
  createdBy: () => User;
}

export const CompanySchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(Company);
```

**user.schema.ts**

```
@Schema({
  timestamps: true,
  versionKey: false,
})
export class User {
  @Prop({
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Company',
    required: true,
  })
  companyId: () => Company;

  @Prop({ type: String, trim: true, required: true })
  firstName: string;

  @Prop({ type: String, trim: true, required: true })
  lastName: string;

  @Prop({ type: String, trim: true, required: true, unique: true })
  email: string;

  @Prop({ type: String, trim: true })
  password: string;

  @Prop({ type: Boolean, required: true, default: false })
  isDeleted: boolean;

}

export const UserSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(User);
```

Now when i trying to access nested property which i getting from user data using `findOne`.

```
const user = await this.userModel
    .findOne(
      { _id: payload.id, isDeleted: false, isActive: true },
    )
    .populate('companyId')
    .lean();

  if (user.companyId.isDeleted && user.companyId.isDeleted === false)
    throw new UnauthorizedException(CONSTANT.NOT_FOUND('User'));
```

Its give me a typescript error that

> Property 'isDeleted' does not exist on type '() => Company'.

How can i fix this typescript issue.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried
`@Prop({ type: Boolean, required: true, default: false }) public isDeleted: boolean;`

Comment: You can see in company.entity.ts file that i have shared in question. Did you go through it?

Comment: yes i see it. I am not sure what is the default visibility of props. so i am pointing to add public before isDeleted Prop  "public isDeleted: boolean;"